# How can I pair objects to radio buttons?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I'm working on a small form app, and I have "paired" my radio buttons with lists in a common class. The purpose of this was to turn on/off the corresponding list

```
public class myType
{
    public RadioButton button { get; set; }
    public ListBox list { get; set; }
}
```

I proceed to create these pairs through a for loop inside an array

```
for (int i = 0; i < broj_botuna; i++)
{
    theArray[i] = new myType();
}
```

I use a common event handler for all the radio buttons:

```
private void test_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var xx = sender as RadioButton;
    //do stuff
    positionInArray = Array.IndexOf(theArray, xx);
}
```

except that the last line of code "xx" should be of type "myType" and not "radioButton" that I managed to retrieve.

So could anyone tell me how do I get the reference from "radioButton" to "myType"?  Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Is this an HTML form you're talking about? WPF? WinForms? Each technology presents different challenges on how to answer this.

Comment: @krillgar I just guessed winforms based entirely on the name of the event handler.  I guess I could be wrong and it's WPF.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I could even see WebForms.

Comment: @krillgar Why does UI technology matters here?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The way the question was originally worded made it sound like pulling the items not just through the array. Basically, a roundabout way of asking for clarification on a question I found a bit vague at first glance.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying. its WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy(v=vs.110).aspx) like:

```
var positionInArray = Array.FindIndex(theArray, b => b.button == xx);
```

Comment: still working on it, but I think it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could create some constructs that allow you to easily associate your properties to the parent object if you wanted to.

This approach would allow you to always reference your parent type provided that you added a bit more code in your get's and set's.

```
static void Main()
{
    myType item = new myType();

    var button = new Button();
    myType.button = button;

    var list = new ListBox();
    myType.list = list;

    item = list.GetParent();
    bool isSameButton = button == item.button;
    bool isSameList = list == item.list;

    Assert.IsTrue(isSameButton);
    Assert.IsTrue(isSameList);
}

public class myType
{
    private RadioButton _button;
    public RadioButton button
    {
        get { return _button; }
        set {
                value.AssociateParent(this);
                _button = value;
            }
    }

    private ListBox _list;
    public ListBox list
    {
        get { return _list; }
        set {
                value.AssociateParent(this);
                _list= value;
            }
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    private static Dictionary<object, object> Items { get; set; }

    static Extensions()
    {
        Items = new Dictionary<object, object>();
    }

    public static void AssociateParent(this object child, object parent)
    {
        Items[child] = parent;
    }

    public static object GetParent(this object child)
    {
        if (Items.ContainsKey(child)) return Items[child];
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll take a look at it, and tell you how it goes. I appreciate your effort. 
I'm still a newb... so any alternative method will give me great dividend. 
Ty!

Comment: thank you very much. I've never used assert before, and it's a whole new tool for me! I really appreciate it.